# Getting xml file through command-line php script

Tags: php, xml, command-line, curl, file-get-contents

How do I get the content of an xml file through a command line php script?  If I access this link through the IE browser, I am able to get the XML file: `http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/ma.php?x=0`.  If I try to get the file through command line with `c:\path\php.exe get_advisory_upd.php`, the script shows an error `host did not respond in allowed time`.  This seems to be a security issue.  I must have a scheduled task to get that xml at specified intervals.  How do I do that?  file_get_contents() returned that same error, simplexml_load_file() might not have shown any errors, but did not get the xml file.

PHP Script get_advisory_upd.php:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$file = 'atom-advisory-MAZ015_UPD.txt';
$newfile = 'atom-advisory-MAZ015.txt.bak';

if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
    echo "Failed to copy $file...\n";
}

/* $contents = file_get_contents('http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/ma.php?x=0'); */

// Use cURL to get the RSS feed into a PHP string variable.
$ref_url = "http://192.x.x.x/weather/get_advisory_upd.php";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/ma.php?x=0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $ref_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1000);
$contents = curl_exec($ch);
echo 'Curl error: '. curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

/* $contents = simplexml_load_file('http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/ma.php?x=0');

echo "contents \n".$contents; */

file_put_contents($file, $contents);

?>
```

UPDATE

I am running this script from an intranet.  As y_a_v_a suggested I specified the CURLOPT_REFERER option to tell the remote host my url.  I do that with

```
$ref_url = "http://192.x.x.x/weather/get_advisory_upd.php";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $ref_url);
```

Is there a different way to specify the URL?

Answer (score 1):

Set a sane CURLOPT_REFERER and set CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT to zero and run your script. Verify what happens by adding

```
$curl_error = curl_error($ch);
```

and dump $curl_error after you closed the curl action.

Comment: The error it got is: `Curl error: couldn't connect to hostcontents.`

Comment: I should also mention that I am running this script from an intranet.  To specify the URL on CURLOPT_REFERER, I provide the host ip address like this `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $ref_url);` with $ref_url set to `$ref_url = "http://192.x.x.x/weather/get_advisory_upd.php";`.

Comment: Did you ping the URL from your server, to see if it is accessible? Funny thing is that I can't ping the host but running `curl http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/ma.php?x=0` from my command line I do get xml...

Comment: Your script appears to work fine, couldn't it just be a router / firewall setting?

Comment: The ping request for weather.gov timed out.  What router/firewall settings could affect whether the script get the xml? Thanks.